# Can I use an arbitrary string as an Elasticsearch id field?

Tags: elasticsearch

It does not seem from the documentation that there are any limitations apart from the size of the field, but what I am wondering is if it will impact the performance. I.e. would Elastic be able to index optimally if I use special characters, like dash, underscore, semicolon etc.?

An example that I want to use (it is not meant to be queryable, but unique):

`2023-02-20T13:57:32.848Z_7_33434934`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: elasticsearch (1) can store strings with special character in it, (2) performance depends on the mapping of the field

to maximise performance:

- if you don't want to query over that field, but still sorting and aggregating over it, you can assign it with a "keyword" data type ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)) and disable indexing ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html))
- if you don't want to query over that field + not sorting + not aggregating over it, you can assign it with a "object" data type and set the property `enabled = false` ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html))

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a default id field and I will not be doing queries against it. I just want it to be unique and not degraded performance if suddenly elasticsearch likes its own generated ids more than the ones I generate